# Cannot edit condition/action columns in DecisionTable

Tags: ibm-odm

I am using the Eclipse ODM Rule Editor and in the past I have been able to define some operations and use simple DecisionTables, specifying conditions and action columns.

Fast forward a couple months to today, I add a DecisionTable to my rules and I am unable to click on the  or  of any columns, these words are greyed out. I tried creating new projects, etc, it just doesn't work.

The only difference between now and when I had this working was the incoming data. My first "tests" were with simple BOMs like strings or XOM to BOM from simple objects I created myself.
Now my project uses a set of java objects created from a codegen of a swagger file to represent a "Form", with "Form Sections", "Fields" and such

I wonder could it be something with the type of BOMs I use may prevent me from using a DecisionTable?

Comment: Eclipse is not perfect; Rule Designer plugin is not perfect. Especially older versions. Have you tried shutting down Eclipse and starting it up again?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is the type of XOM you are using; that should not affect the decision table editor. Even with no XOM or BOM, you should be able to create a decision table and specify conditions and actions; you would be limited to the built-in vocabulary, but the editor should work fine.

You could try an experiment. From within Rule Designer in your existing Eclipse workspace with the new XOM/BOM, create a new Rule Project as a Main Rule Project with no references to any other projects. You should be able to create a decision table in the rules folder of that rule project and edit the condition and action columns. This would prove your Rule Designer environment is set up and working properly.

Next, you could try to create an Action Rule, instead of a decision table, in the rule project where you're having problems with the decision table. This would prove the BOM/XOM is working fine, but the decision table editor is not.

It is a separate issue whether there is are any BOM elements for your new XOM. Or whether those BOM elements are verbalized. Or whether any verbalized BOM elements are visible in a particular decision table.

If these experiments do not lead to a solution to your problem, please add more details to your question, such as ODM version, what Java projects and what Rule projects you have set up.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Action rules are fine. I have a bunch of business objects verbalized and I am able to do RuleFlow with Action rules, all kinds of other elements are working fine. I will start another project from scratch and go steps by steps as you suggested, and come back here with an update

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. I had to double click on the condition or action column header, not try to click on the  or  keyword in the title bar.
Oh my...